# PHP PDO wont update database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

i try to use PDO but i get 1,1,1 for result but database wont updated. I dont know whats wrong with my code.

```
try {$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host", $db_user, $db_pass );}
catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}

$title_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_title = ? WHERE id = ?");
$title_insert->bindParam(1, $id);
$title_insert->bindParam(2, $topic_title);

$tag_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_tags = ? WHERE id = ?");
$tag_insert->bindParam(1, $id);
$tag_insert->bindParam(2, $topic_tags);

$story_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_story = ? WHERE id = ?");
$story_insert->bindParam(1, $id);
$story_insert->bindParam(2, $topic_story);


$id = 1;
$topic_title = "title";
$topic_tags = "tags";
$topic_story = "story";

$result_title = $title_insert->execute();
echo $sonuc_title.',';

$sonuc_tag = $tag_insert->execute();
echo $sonuc_tag.',';

$result_story = $story_insert->execute();
echo $result_story;
```

Thanks for answers...

Comment: Do you really need 3 UPDATE's on 1 record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried switching the param numbers?

```
$title_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_title = ? WHERE id = ?");
$title_insert->bindParam(1, $topic_title);
$title_insert->bindParam(2, $id);
```

Good luck!

[PDO Bind param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0):

you should affect your variable before the bind statement :

```
$id = 1;
$topic_title = "title";
$topic_tags = "tags";
$topic_story = "story";

$title_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_title = ? WHERE id = ?");
$title_insert->bindParam(1, $id);
$title_insert->bindParam(2, $topic_title);

$tag_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_tags = ? WHERE id = ?");
$tag_insert->bindParam(1, $id);
$tag_insert->bindParam(2, $topic_tags);

$story_insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE topics SET topic_story = ? WHERE id = ?");
$story_insert->bindParam(1, $id);
$story_insert->bindParam(2, $topic_story);


$result_title = $title_insert->execute();
echo $sonuc_title.',';

$sonuc_tag = $tag_insert->execute();
echo $sonuc_tag.',';

$result_story = $story_insert->execute();
echo $result_story;
```